# Reactjs => react-simple-tree-menu get & show api

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I'm stuck here when I want to display a list of province names in the TreeMenu.

So my expectation is like this ->
[image]

However I don't know how to render from an endpoint. please help me, thank you.

The Endpoint = https://www.mocky.io/v3/4c38e8a1-aa12-484d-900e-2c67726a09bf

My Code =

```
import React from "react";
import TreeMenu from "react-simple-tree-menu";
import "react-simple-tree-menu/dist/main.css";

            <TreeMenu
              cacheSearch
              data={[
                {
                  key: "provinsi",
                  label: "Provinsi",
                  nodes: [
                    {
                      key: "aceh",
                      label: "ACEH",
                      nodes: [
                        {
                          key: "total_building",
                          label: "902705",
                          nodes: [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      key: "bali",
                      label: "BALI",
                      nodes: [
                        {
                          key: "total_building",
                          label: "1584831",
                          nodes: [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    {
                      key: "banten",
                      label: "BANTEN",
                      nodes: [
                        {
                          key: "total_building",
                          label: "2043597",
                          nodes: [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ]}
              debounceTime={125}
              disableKeyboard={false}
              hasSearch={false}
              onClickItem={function noRefCheck() {}}
              resetOpenNodesOnDataUpdate={false}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TreeMenu from "react-simple-tree-menu";
import "react-simple-tree-menu/dist/main.css";
import axios from "axios";

const TreeList = () => {
  const [countData, setCount] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.mocky.io/v3/4c38e8a1-aa12-484d-900e-2c67726a09bf`)
      .then((resolve) => {
        console.log(resolve);
        setCount(resolve);
      })
      .catch((reject) => {
        console.log(reject);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  console.log(countData.data?.provinsi)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col text-center">
          <p className="mt-3">
            <div className="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center cursor-pointer">
              <div className="col-lg-8 text-left text-dark">
                <TreeMenu
                  cacheSearch
                  data={[
                    {
                      key: "provinsi",
                      label: "Provinsi",
                      nodes: [
                        {
                          key: "aceh",
                          label: countData.map((el) => <div key={el.id}>{el.provinsi}</div>),
                          nodes: [
                            {
                              key: "total_building",
                              label: "902705",
                              nodes: [],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                        // {
                        //   key: "bali",
                        //   label: "BALI",
                        //   nodes: [
                        //     {
                        //       key: "total_building",
                        //       label: "1584831",
                        //       nodes: [],
                        //       url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=fox",
                        //     },
                        //   ],
                        //   url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=fox",
                        // },
                        // {
                        //   key: "banten",
                        //   label: "BANTEN",
                        //   nodes: [
                        //     {
                        //       key: "total_building",
                        //       label: "2043597",
                        //       nodes: [],
                        //       url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=fox",
                        //     },
                        //   ],
                        //   url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=wolf",
                        // },
                      ],
                      url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=mammal",
                    },
                  ]}
                  debounceTime={125}
                  disableKeyboard={false}
                  hasSearch={false}
                  onClickItem={function noRefCheck() {}}
                  resetOpenNodesOnDataUpdate={false}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TreeList;
```